# What does "+ 3" in while (*(MPcore_private_timer_ptr + 3) == 0) mean?

Tags: arm, fpga, intel-fpga, soc

I am currently reading through DE0-Nano-SoC Computer System
with ARM Cortex-A9 user guide i found a c code in it and i don't understand what does  "+ 3"  in "*(MPcore_private_timer_ptr + 3)" mean?

```
while (1)
{
*HPS_GPIO1_ptr = HPS_LEDG; // turn on/off LEDG
while (*(MPcore_private_timer_ptr + 3) == 0)
; // wait for timer to expire
*(MPcore_private_timer_ptr + 3) = 1; // reset timer flag bit
HPS_LEDG ^= bit_24_pattern; // toggle bit that controls LEDG
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Blockquote
>
> *(MPcore_private_timer_ptr + 3) = 1; // reset timer flag bit

Is synonimum of :

> *(&MPcore_private_timer_ptr[3]) = 1; // reset timer flag bit

Answer (score 1):

`*(MPcore_private_timer_ptr + 3)` is the same as `MPcore_private_timer_ptr[3]`.
You dereference an incremented pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Following on for @yar's answer, `MPcore_private_timer_ptr` is a pointer to the base address of a memory mapped timer, that is the timer's registers all follow on from that address. The +3 offset takes you to a different register (in this case the interrupt status register) for that timer.